# What's wrong with this recursion method? Count number of matching elements that are in same index in 2 vectors

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to debug this program to find the number of matching elements that occur at the same index in 2 different vectors. Requirement is to NOT use any loops

> Code on online compiler: http://cpp.sh/8rvtj

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int calls=0;
int matchCount(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2, int i=0)
{
    calls++;
    static int smallVecSz=-1;
    smallVecSz = (v1.size()<v2.size() ? v1.size() : v2.size());
    static int ans=0;

    if(i==smallVecSz)
    {
        cout << "Returning " << ans << endl;
        return ans;
    }

    // if element at index i is same in v1 and v2, add 1 to ans else add 0 to ans
    ans += (v1[i]==v2[i] ? 1 : 0);

    return ans + matchCount(v1,v2,i+1); // pass optional param index i+1 to advance to next ele

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = {2, 5, 2, 1, 8, 9, 1, 6, 9, 2};
    vector<int> v2 = {2, 5, 3, 0, 8, 4, 1};

    cout << "There are " << matchCount(v1,v2) << " matching numbers at same indexes" << endl;
    cout << "Number of Recursion calls: " << calls << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Here is a sample input:

> vector v1 = {2, 5, 2, 1, 8, 9, 1, 6, 9, 2};
>
> vector v2 = {2, 5, 3, 0, 8, 4, 1};

### Here is a sample output:

> Returning **4**
>
> There are **32** matching numbers at same indexes
>
> Number of Recursion calls: **8**

My program is recursive function is correctly returning the ans 4. But the main program is printing 32.

Comment: What is the interrest to have _smallVecSz_ static ?

Comment: Due to the fact, that `ans` is `static` and due to your return condition, your function effectively returns `ans * (v1.size()<v2.size() ? v1.size() : v2.size())` = `4 * 8` = `32`.

Comment: You not only accumulate answer in `ans` (because it's marked as `static`, it basically becomes a global variable, just like `calls`), but you also multiply it by the number of recursive calls when returning from `matchCount`.

Comment: Put `cout << "ans = " << ans << "\n";` before the line `return ans + matchCount(v1,v2,i+1);` and look at the output. This will help you to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, a static variable accumulating in a recursive function is a code smell.

Normally, when you use recursion, each call starts with a clean an fresh environment.
In that case, you accumulate the value of each call with its children to find the total.

Alternatively, you can use a static variable which is updated by each call and just used by the top parent.

But here you are mixing both approaches, actually getting a much too high value.

So 2 ways here:

1. make `ans` an automatic (non static) variable:

   ```
   ...
   smallVecSz = (v1.size()<v2.size() ? v1.size() : v2.size());
   int ans=0;

   if(i==smallVecSz)
   ...
   ```
2. keep `ans` static, and do not accumulate:

   ```
   ...
   ans += (v1[i]==v2[i] ? 1 : 0);
   matchCount(v1, v2, i+1); // pass optional param index i+1 to advance to next ele
   return ans;
   ...
   ```

   Of course in that case, you will get wrong results if you call the function more than once because `ans` will not be reset to 0 (Thanks to @bruno for noticing)

Comment: I hope @Manjunath understands that with _ans_ static the function cannot be called more than one time to return the right result (except of course of the first times the result was 0 :) )

Answer (score 1):

your problem comes from ans being static and the fact you return it when you reach the end of the vector rather than 0 etc

I do not understand too why that function is recursive

Comment: my requirement was to not use loops

Comment: @Manjunath you should put that information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

a solution with a loop and an other with recursion as you requested in a comment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int matchCount(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2)
{
   vector<int>::const_iterator it1;
   vector<int>::const_iterator it2;
   int result = 0;

   for (it1 = v1.begin(), it2 = v2.begin();
        (it1 != v1.end()) && (it2 != v2.end());
        ++it1, ++it2) {
     if (*it1 == *it2)
       result += 1;
   }

   return result;
}

int recurMatchCount(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2, int i = 0)
{
  return ((i == v1.size()) || (i == v2.size()))
    ? 0
    : (((v1[i] == v2[i]) ? 1 : 0)
      + recurMatchCount(v1, v2, i + 1));
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = {2, 5, 2, 1, 8, 9, 1, 6, 9, 2};
    vector<int> v2 = {2, 5, 3, 0, 8, 4, 1};

    cout << "There are " << matchCount(v1,v2) << " matching numbers at same indexes" << endl;
    cout << "There are " << recurMatchCount(v1,v2) << " recur matching numbers at same indexes" << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: of course the number of recursions calls is `min(v1.size(),v2.size()) - 1`

Comment: I'd be tempted to use the fact that `true` promotes to `1` and `false` to `0` to simplify the arithmetic

Comment: @Caleth you cannot suppose ((int) true) is 1, this is probable but not sure. Furthermore even it is true that changes nothing on the generated code, the compiler will certainly generate the same thing in both cases

Comment: @Caleth ok, thank you for the reference, I didn't know. But again be sure the generated code is the same.

Comment: Thanks @bruno. That's really concise and clear code.